# Measuring the TCP Bytes waiting to be read by the Socket

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I have a socket connection that receives data, and reads it for processing.
When data is not processed/pulled fast enough from the socket, there is a bottleneck at the TCP level, and the data received is delayed (I can tell by the tmestamps after parsing).

How can I see how much TCP bytes are awaiting to be read by the socket ? (via some external tool like WireShark or else)

```
 private void InitiateRecv(IoContext rxContext)
    {
        rxContext._ipcSocket.BeginReceive(rxContext._ipcBuffer.Buffer, rxContext._ipcBuffer.WrIndex,
            rxContext._ipcBuffer.Remaining(), 0, CompleteRecv, rxContext);
    }

    private void CompleteRecv(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        IoContext rxContext = ar.AsyncState as IoContext;
        if (rxContext != null)
        {
               int rxBytes = rxContext._ipcSocket.EndReceive(ar);

                if (rxBytes > 0)
                {
                    EventHandler<VfxIpcEventArgs> dispatch = EventDispatch;
                        dispatch (this, new VfxIpcEventArgs(rxContext._ipcBuffer));

                    InitiateRecv(rxContext);

                }
          }
     }
```

The fact is that I guess the "dispatch" is somehow blocking the reception until it is done, ending up in latency (i.e, data that is processed bu the dispatch is delayed, hence my (false?) conclusion that there was data accumulated on the socket level or before.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I see how much TCP bytes are awaiting to be read by the socket

By specifying a protocol that indicates how many bytes it's about to send. Using sockets you operate a few layers above the byte level, and you can't see how many `send()` calls end up as `receive()` calls on your end because of buffering and delays.

If you specify the number of bytes on beforehand, and send a string like `"13|Hello, World!"`, then there's no problem when the message arrives in two parts, say `"13|Hello"` and `", World!"`, because you know you'll have to read 13 bytes.

You'll have to keep some sort of state and a buffer in between different `receive()` calls.

Comment: I am afraid I did not really understand what you mean : I have no control over the send level so far. I am just listening to a stream sent by an external server

Comment: @MikaJacobi then I don't understand what exactly you want to do. What are you doing and what problem are you trying to solve? You can only see how many bytes your socket has received (i.e. how many bytes are in the buffer, ready to be presented through `Receive()`). You can request this number using the `Socket.Available` property. There is no way of knowing on beforehand how many bytes are currently "on the wire" or even further up, in the send buffer of the other end.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding I am very new to this. Please see edit.

Comment: What do you think about my comment on Rajesh's post ?

Comment: @MikaJacobi now I kind of get it - you call                   `InitiateRecv(rxContext);` after processing the data you received before that. When processing takes a while, there will be more data ready for the socket, which will only be read after .EndReceive is called - this is normal. If you want to receive data faster than you can process, you'll have to offload processing to another thread and use something like a synchronized queue to keep adding received data to.

Comment: Yes indeed, you are totally right. I already did that. The problem with this alternative is that it creates latency. I have to avoid that, as part of sepcs & requirements. So all i want is to "peek" and see how much data is accumulated and waiting to be read. Now I am wondering why available bytes are topped @ "8192"...

Comment: @MikaJacobi because that is the [default receive buffer size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivebuffersize.aspx). Your server is sending more data to you, but until you empty your sockets' buffer (by calling `.EndReceive()`), no more data is received.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `socket.Available`  if you are  using normal `Socket` class. Otherwise you have to define a header byte which gives number of bytes to be sent from other end.

Comment: Hey that was nice. It confirmed my intuition : The Socket.Avail returns 0, constantly, until I cause a bottleneck on purpose on runtime in the processing step, and boom, there it goes to 8192. This probably means that data awaiting to be erad by the socket is crowding at its door

Comment: @MikaJacobi It means there is no data, and if you are calling the Avail method in a tight loop you are just wasting time. There is no such thing as 'crowding at its door'.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to external tools like Wireshark, they cannot know how many bytes are left in the socket. They only know which packets have passed by the network interface.
The only way to check it with Wireshark is to actually know the last bytes you read from the socket, locate them in Wireshark, and count from there.

However, the best way to get this information is to check the Available property on the socket object in your .NET application.